# Best statistical model for ranked preferences

Tags: statistics, aggregate, rank, policy, survey

I need some help figuring out the best statistical model for my planned research.

Here is the setup: I want to understand support for four distinct policies. More specifically, I want to understand the order of preference of these four policies. I plan to collect this data via a survey.

I am doubtful whether asking respondents to rank the preferences themselves will be helpful. Since this could be a somewhat cognitively challenging task, I am afraid that many respondents will simply skip the question.

My alternative strategy is deploying standard 10-point likert scale questions for each policy. As in: “If 0 is the lowest and 10 is the highest, how much would you support the president implementing policy Pn” and so on three more times.

My question is as follows: what would be the best statistical model to calculate individual order of preferences? This is a challenge to me since I do not expect absolute transitivity to hold up at an individual level. I am expecting a lot of people to give the same likability score to two or more policies.

Question 1) To reprise the question: what statistical model should I use?

Question 2) Lets relax the assumption that respondents will skip more cognitively challenging questions. I welcome any other “outside the box” setup suggestions. For instance, instead of asking four individual feeling thermometer questions, a role-playing scenario where the respondent plays the role of an incumbent and has to decide how to break the budget down between four government agencies. (The policies are not inherently contradictory amongst themselves.)
Thank you

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming question; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Hadn't had any luck there so far.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Another idea is to try the r-help mailing list.